# How to make horizontal/customize Bootstrap drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

`HTML` page contents age selector as a `Bootstrap` `drop-down`. I want to put `li` tags in horizontally as follows. how use `css` to achieve it? following `css` is no working

```
#horizontalmenu {display:inline} /*not working*/
```

[image] => [image]

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Age<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="horizontalmenu">
      <li><a href="#">21</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">22</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">23</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">24</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">25</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">26</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">27</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">28</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll want to apply that css to the `li`, not the `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

You need to add `float:left` to the `li`

**Working Demo**

```css
li{
  float:left;
}
ul{
  width:250px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Age<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="horizontalmenu">
      <li><a href="#">21</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">22</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">23</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">24</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">25</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">26</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">27</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">28</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the `li` and not the `ul`. I would float the `li` to the `left`. Then limit the width of `#horizontalmenu`.

```css
#horizontalmenu {
  max-width: 225px; /* appx. width of 4 li */
}
#horizontalmenu > li {
  float: left;
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9svk6av/).

You could also use `display: inline-block;` on the `li` but there will be small gaps of space between each `li` relative to the font size. Although there are workarounds for the spaces created by inline elements, it's usually easier to float that inline-block if those spaces become an issue.